# ASP.NET DetailsView custom forward only paging

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, detailsview

In my aspx page I have a DetailsView and a SqlDataSource and a button labeled "Next".
The datasource mode has been set to DataReader since i only need to advance forward.

In my cs page, I have:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        comm = new SqlCommand("PickRandomQuestions", conn);
        comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comm.Parameters.Add("QuizID", SqlDbType.Int);
        comm.Parameters["QuizID"].Value = 1;
        conn.Open();
        reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
        QuestionDetails.DataSource = reader;
        QuestionDetails.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void ButtonNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        QuestionDetails.DataSource = reader;
        QuestionDetails.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        conn.Close();
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

Now when i click on the Next button, i get System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You have to initiallize reader inside the ButtonNext_Click.

Comment: @kostasch. Thanks. but if i do, won't the command get executed again?! i only want to execute it once and it should return a random unique record set. right? how do i go about that issue?

Comment: I aggree with you BUT the specific error dirives from that :).

Comment: @kostasch. then this leaves the second part of my previous question unanswered (how do i go about this? ) :) ... appreciate it!

Comment: @kostasch. what i need is away to keep my record set across post backs ... right? how can i achieve that? I need an example to make things clear.